# Focus TextBox and select all text after window initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, focus

When a new window is opened, I want to focus a specific textbox and select the whole text in it.
I tried it on base of this tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/2013/04/12/a-simple-selectall-behavior-for-textboxes/

For focussing the element I use this in my Grid:

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{StaticResource DesignTimeLayerViewModel1}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=LayerNameInput}">
```

And tried it with an interaction behavior:

```
<TextBox x:Name="LayerNameInput"
    Text="{Binding MapLayerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Width="240">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior></behaviors:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Behavior Code:

```
public class SelectAllTextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus += this.OnTextBoxGotFocus;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= this.OnTextBoxGotFocus;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

The Problem is the binding. When the window is created, the behavior fires correct, but actually there is no text in the TextBox. Then the TextBox is initialized and set the text to the value of the binded variable and the selection is lost.
If I refocus the TextBox by use multiple times Tab, it works fine.

How is it possible to focus a TextBox and select its whole text on window creation? Without a massive amount of code behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with a workaround. When the intial text of the TextBox is set during window startup, the OnTextBoxTextChanged event is fired. I just catch it, select the text and than deatach the event.

The benefit of this compared to your answer Dark Templar is, that when I focus the TextBox again e.g. with tab, the whole text is selected again.

```
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += OnTextBoxGotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= OnTextBoxGotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextBoxTextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
    }

    private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could use the "window_loaded" event to focus your textbox
here's an example:

```
    private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an attached property to do this.

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An attached property that, when set to true, causes a TextBox to select
    /// all its text when it receives focus. Assumes that the TextBox's lifecycle
    /// matches its parent user control's lifecycle.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectTextOnFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SelectTextOnFocus",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TextBoxExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectTextOnFocusChanged));

    public static bool GetSelectTextOnFocus(TextBox textBox) => (bool)textBox.GetValue(SelectTextOnFocusProperty);

    public static void SetSelectTextOnFocus(TextBox textBox, bool value) => textBox.SetValue(SelectTextOnFocusProperty, value);

    private static void OnSelectTextOnFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox textBox && e.NewValue is bool b)
        {
            if (b) textBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
            else textBox.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
        }

        void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

You declare the namespace of the extension in your XAML, I use "ext" for my extensions.

Then, to apply it, just set the property.

```
<TextBox x:Name="_quantity" ext:TextBoxExtensions.SelectTextOnFocus="True" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Overkill if you're just doing it in one place, but if you've got a form where you want this behavior on a lot of text boxes, this, with a style makes it easy.